# How to remove login dialog box when user logged in?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a problem in my website that is when the home page of my website loads it shows a dialog box for login and when registered user logged in it says log out but also my login dialog box reappears though I am logged in, I think its because of loading the same page again because I am calling the onload event inside body tag which calls external JavaScript's file function. I want once the user login the login dialog box should not appear again. Any idea?

Comment: your question is very abstract. no recomendations can't be given without more details. providing with programming code is the best.

Answer (score 1):

May be once the user presses the logged in button you should always check the session variable, if this is NOT null, then hide the log in panel!

Comment: Can I do with the help of javascript?

Comment: You must first insert contents into session variable from the code behind. after doing that you can check in javascript: VAR user = ('<%=Session.Contents["USERID"]%>') if (user != null) { log in panel visible} else { hide log in panel }